# Grouped UITableView has 20px of extra padding at the bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Grouped table views seem to have extra padding on the bottom in iOS 6 (iOS 5 does not have it), but I can't find any documentation that suggests this is correct / expected behavior.

This affects the example projects as well, for instance the `SimpleTableView` project in the `TableViewSuite` example.  I think I had to change the style in the `AppDelegate` to 'grouped', and updated the SDK to iOS 6, but no other changes have been made to the project.

Investigating revealed that there are `10px` reserved for header and footer views, plus some `20px` that can't be accounted for.
There are no actual header or footer views (`tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` are `nil`, and implementing and returning `nil` for e.g. `viewForFooterInSection` does nothing).
I cannot find any '20' value on the tableView itself, though I may have missed something of course.

Adding a zero-size view for the footer does nothing, but adding a `1px` square view causes the extra padding to vanish. e.g.:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
```

It does take up `1px` of height still, so the bottom padding is now `11px`, but this is far less noticeable than 20.  And now setting the `sectionFooterHeight` to 0 will result in only `1px` of bottom-space.

My question is: what?  And how can I completely remove it?  This isn't anything mission-critical, but it is extremely weird, undesirable, and as far as I can tell it's undocumented.

Please note - its copy past question from apple dev forum. But I have exactly the same issue and I don't understand how to solve it too.

Comment: Found the same issue here :(

Comment: If you are still using SO, you should award the answer to Frank White, as his solution works great in iOS8.3. Setting the footer value to zero has no effect.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

@frankWhite' solution works great, but here is a better solution to avoid typing 0.1, 0.001 or others to make it less ambiguous.

```
// Swift version
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    // remove bottom extra 20px space.
    return CGFloat.min
}
```

```swift
// Swift 5 version
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    // remove bottom extra 20px space.
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

```
// Objective-C version
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // remove bottom extra 20px space.
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Comment: Good work building on @frankWhite's answer to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: In order to make it work use this func prototype: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`

Comment: `return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` in swift 3.0 and higher

Comment: I also had to implement `viewForFooterInSection` returning `nil` to make it work in iOS 11+

Comment: Unfortunately not doing anything for me. I even update the function signature to `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`, function gets called, no dice, iOS 13

Answer (score 33):

You can use `contentInset` to compensate the 20px extra bottom margin:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -20, 0);
```

Comment: works for me. But this is sounding arbitrary. Why did I get space in the top for my grouped table starting ios5.0 in the first place?

Comment: @Gmu I don't know. Apple always arbitrarily adjusts UIKit to its own fit, which often leaves us 3rd-party devs fumbling :( iOS 7 is even worse in this aspect.

Answer (score 17):

in Swift 3

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 0.01;
}
```

It's work for me

Comment: Brilliant! Setting it to 0 has no effect. I even used 0.0001. I'm using Xcode 6.3 for iOS8.3 so this is working on latest release of Xcode.

Comment: I suggest going with @BensonTommy's answer as it is less ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you so much! What a terrible API the poor, sad UITableView has. Time to rewrite from the ground-up. But hopefully, without UICollectionViewController's rampant verbosity!

Answer (score 3):

This is the only working solution I guess.I tried setting `tableFooterView` and `tableHeaderView` to `nil`.
But nothing happened.Then the following solution worked .Returning zero **"return 0;"** has no effect.We should return the lowest possible height.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    }
```

**NOTE:**
This is what I got when printed the values.

> CGFLOAT_MAX = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
>
> CGFLOAT_MIN = 0.000000

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I found this issue, and followed the solutions posted above, but all of them doesn't work. In my case, I have a section header with dynamic height. Inspired by the above solutions, I put following code, and problem solved. I hope this can help.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1
}
```

and config tableView's header and footer like this:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0.1))
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0.1))
```

Comment: Good call to set tableFooterView, strange but it works. I already have tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) implemented, so I tried adding the heightForFooter and viewForFooter section as described here and like other answers, those didn't fix it for me, but creating a dummy tableFooterView worked.

Comment: if (@available(iOS 15.0, *))

{
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 0.1))
}
Solved my problem. Thx

Answer (score 1):

this solves the issue:

**Obj-c**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 0.1;
    }
```

**Swift:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2 you can try setting table header with least normal magnitude height -

```
var frame = CGRect.zero
frame.size.height = .leastNormalMagnitude
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesnt work for me. I need to replace not section footer but table footer. Only one thing that can help is  tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)]; but it decrease padding to 1px not absolutelly remove it.

Comment: I have face similar issue in a grouped tableview for login & password. But solved using this. Have you try `tableView.tableFooterView = nil;`

Comment: Yes i try to setup tableFooterView to nil, but it doesnt work for me. Looks like compiler ignores it. I have many sections so i cant use your code. But also if i just create a clear project with only one groupped tableview it work in the same way ads extra padding at the bottom. Even settings app have the same padding.

Comment: Setting tableFooterView to nil worked for me! Thanks! Throw that in your answer and ill give it a +1

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 code**

```
class PaddingLessTableView : UITableView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
 tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: .leastNormalMagnitude))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `bounces` property of `UIScrollView`:

```
[yourTableView setBounces:NO];
```

This will remove what seems to be an extra padding at the top and bottom of your `UITableView`.
Actually, it will just disable the tableview's scrollview to scroll past the edge of the content.