# UITableView extra space at bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

My tableview has an extra space at the bottom, as you see in the picture:

All the rows in the tableView have a fixed height of 71pt.

[image]

Comment: When you pull the view up from there, where does the scrollbar appear to bounce at?

Comment: @Tommy At the same position from the picture

Comment: Only the answer helped me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445770/4593553

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

The "Adjust Scroll View Insets" was marked on my viewController (not my tableView).

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022366/1107651) with a detailed explanation

Answer (score 6):

In my case tableView was created programmaticaly and I had to set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to make the space disappear

Answer (score 5):

@urgentx's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115502/1166266) did most of what I wanted but didn't get all the way there. I'm in a similar situation (upside down UITableView for a chat app) however their suggestion fully disables safe area behavior which isn't desirable on devices like the iPhone X because it means the tableview will be clipped by both the home indicator and any top navigation bars.

I did the following in order to make the tableview still correctly avoid safe areas while inverted:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

and then:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    //fetch the safe area in layoutSubviews since this it's possible that they can change when the device is rotated
    let safeArea = self.tableView.safeAreaInsets
    //insets are **flipped** because the tableview is flipped over its Y-axis!
    self.tableView.contentInset = .init(top: safeArea.bottom, left: 0, bottom: safeArea.top, right: 0)
}
```

This in essence replicates `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic` behavior but with the insets flipped across the Y-axis.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was due to having a footer of height 18 by default at the bottom of the UITableView. Setting it to 1 removed the extra space at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it can be fixed easily through Storyboard (iOS 11):

Select Table View > Size Inspector > Content Insets: Never

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, with latest Xcode (11.3) with latest iOS (13.3) iPhone. I tried many answers, but none worked.

My `tableView` has top, bottom, leading, and trail constraints but somehow there is large space at bottom below the last cell. (`tableView.contentSize.height` was almost double of what is needed) Data for `tableView` is not dynamic at all.It happens both when the view controller that has it shows it and when `tableView` is hidden then shown again.

I solved it by using scrollView's delegate method like below, so that when the user starts dragging, height is adjusted. For me, it works so great, hope for you, too!

```
// this is the best place to adjust the contentSize.height of tableView.
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrollViewWillBeginDragging():") // optional
    // replace allParkingGeos.count with your data for tableView
    tableView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(allParkingGeos.count) * cellHeight
}
```

Comment: thank Brian Hong, it works perfectly. But I'm still curious about this problem.
In my case, I have a tableview with data loaded from SQLite. When no searchBar, it work normally, but when I add searchBar as UITableview header, this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

in this case you can give tableview the bottom space 0 to its superview and it will work i think or you can do,

`tableView.tableFooterView = UIView();`

or you can do like below,

The lower value should be 1.0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    if(section == 0) {
       return 6;
    } else {
       return 1.0;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return 5.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger )section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is no longer a correct one if it comes to iOS 11 and Xcode 9. To achieve similar effect you have to go to Size Inspector where you can find this:

[image]

You can achieve the same in code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I flipped my UITableView upside-down for a chat messaging screen.

Before I flipped the table view, the content inset was leaving a blank space at the top so that when we scrolled all the way up, the content was not obstructed by the navigation bar. Once I flipped it the inset was moved to the bottom.

Change your 'Content Insets' to Never in the Size Inspector of your UITableView to get rid of this space at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is an embedded navigation controller, checking "shows toolbar" creates bottom spacing in the view controller. Just uncheck it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My problem didn't solve by the answers.
i had a `UISearchbar` as `tableHeaderView` which caused the white space ( i don't know why) . I removed the searchbar from tableview in storyboard and in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` added in table header then problem solved.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
}
```

Comment: Recalculating tableView's height in viewWillLayoutSubviews() did solve the issue. I've no idea why, but thank you for the idea!