# viewForFooterInSection not making UITableView Footer stick to bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iphone-x

Yes, I have read a lot of other posts on this issue, none of the solutions have worked for me yet!

Basically, when I use viewForFooterInSection and heightForFooterInSection, the resulting footer "floats"

[image]

viewDidLoad and FooterView code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNaviationBarStyles()
    setUpNavBarButtons()
    navigationItem.title = "Kindle"
    tableView.register(BookCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray 
    fetchBooks()
}   

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

The problem seems to be specific to the iPhone x? In the iPhone 7 simulator the above code works perfectly:

[image]

I have tried to create a custom view in viewDidLoad like a lot of other threads suggested but no such luck yet:

```
let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
view.backgroundColor = .red
self.tableView.tableFooterView = view
```

I appreciate any help around this issue, seems like the solution is probably simple but I have been researching for a while and haven't found anything to be very effective when simulating using an iPhone x.

Cheers!

Comment: This solution work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070782/8366535

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Apple's bug, not yours. They completely failed to think through the implications of the iPhone X.

All you can really do is set the navigation controller's `isToolbarHidden` to `false`, even though you have no toolbar content. That will take up the space behind the home indicator and the table will look decent.

Comment: And file a bug report with Apple, please.