# UItableview at end of scroll there is some extra space

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < controllersArr.count; i++)
{
    UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[controllersArr objectAtIndex:i];
    appDelegate().containerScrollViewHeight=self.containerScrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerScrollView.frame.size.width, self.containerScrollView.frame.size.height);
    frame.origin.x = SCREEN_WIDTH * i;
    vc.view.frame = frame;
    
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.containerScrollView addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Using this coding i added multiple controllers like WhatsApp screen. In "vc" controllers I used UITableView(not UITableview Controller). when I scroll at end there is some extra space, how to remove this space ?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen only on iPhoneX?

Comment: no, it's happen in all device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView extra space at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641280/uitableview-extra-space-at-bottom)