# UITableView(grouped) adds extra empty header at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a bit newbie to objective C and iOS, so my question can be stupid:)
I've checked self.tableData in debug mode, there's no empty items there, and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns correct value. 
Here's UITableView data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSArray *arr = self.tableData[section];
return arr.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sortedDates.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);
    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 20.0f;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return  footer;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section < self.sortedDates.count) {
        UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[tableView rectForHeaderInSection:section]];
      //Setting header appearance
    return sectionHeader;
} else {
    UIView *blankHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:section]];
    blankHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return blankHeader;
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

in simulator:
http://take.ms/rm2DL

in view hierarchy:
http://take.ms/oALdi

This blank space exactly has over 20 points height, so I assume that it should be some kind of odd header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a CGRectZero view for the footer, simply return nil.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  nil;
}
```

Also you do not seem to have implemented `heightForFooterInSection:section`. That should return 0.0.

This seems to have come up before and it would seem iOS often pads the bottom to 20pts. The SO question relates to iOS6 but I notice a comment related to iOS8.3, so probably still relevant. [Grouped UITableView has 20px of extra padding at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210474/grouped-uitableview-has-20px-of-extra-padding-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Thank you, Rory.
This helped:
   
 `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 0.01;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not the footer view which you are returning?
Try changing the footerForSection method there to just return nil

Comment: Tried that, result is still the same. But return nil view is more clear than my solution. So thanks anyway:)